# Wicket and Spring Integration

Tags: java, spring, wicket

I have a wicket contact form, and i receive the form object. Now i need to pass this object to Spring Service.

```
package com.mysticcoders.mysticpaste.web.pages;

import org.apache.wicket.markup.html.WebPage;
import org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form;
import org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.TextField;
import org.apache.wicket.markup.html.panel.FeedbackPanel;
import com.mysticcoders.mysticpaste.model.Contact;
import org.apache.wicket.model.CompoundPropertyModel;

import com.mysticcoders.mysticpaste.services.IContact;


public class FormPage extends WebPage
{

    private Contact contact;
    private IContact icontact;

    public FormPage()
    {
        // Add a FeedbackPanel for displaying our messages
        FeedbackPanel feedbackPanel = new FeedbackPanel("feedback");
        add(feedbackPanel);

        Form<Object> form = new Form<Object>("contactForm",
                new CompoundPropertyModel<Object>(contact))
        {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            protected void onSubmit(Contact contact)
            {               
                icontact.saveContact(contact);
            }
        };  
        form.add(new TextField<Object>("name"));
        form.add(new TextField<Object>("email"));
        form.add(new TextField<Object>("country"));
        form.add(new TextField<Object>("age"));

        add(form);
        // add a simple text field that uses Input's 'text' property. Nothing
        // can go wrong here

   }


}
```

I am pretty much sure that we need to do something with application-context xml where i may need to wire out.

```
My Application-context.xml 

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd">        

    <bean id="WicketApplication" class="com.mysticcoders.mysticpaste.web.pages.WicketApplication" />

</beans>
```

> My Question is simple.

1. What should i do which can make my
   onSubmit method call the Spring
   Service?
2. Could someone let me know what needs
   to modified in my
   Application-context.xml so that once
   the form gets submitted, it contacts
   the Spring Service class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`@SpringBean` answer by mhaller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4550131/wicket-and-spring-intergation/4550169#4550169) is of course valid and considered a best practice by many. But I prefer a more standard Spring approach, where your Wicket Application has the services you need.

```
public class YourWicketApp extends WebApplication{
    public static YourWicketApp get(){
        return (YourWicketApp) Application.get();
    }
    private ServiceA serviceA;
    // getter and setter for serviceA here
}
```

Now in your component, call

```
YourWicketApp.get().getServiceA();
```

There are of course some drawbacks, the biggest one being that you can't easily test such a component without the application.

Comment: Will this approach not tie every component with this specific implementation of WebApplication? So you cannot reuse this 
component in another application.

Comment: little is always affordable :P

Answer (score 9):

[Wicket-Spring](http://wicketstuff.org/wicket13/spring/) integration shows various ways on how to inject Spring Beans (e.g. your IContactService bean) into Wicket pages.

Basically, after configuration of the component injector, you end up with the following code:

```
public class FormPage extends WebPage
{
   @SpringBean
   private IContact icontact;
   ...
     Form<Object> form = new Form<Object>("contactForm",
            new CompoundPropertyModel<Object>(contact))
    {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        protected void onSubmit(Contact contact)
        {               
            icontact.saveContact(contact);
        }
    };
```

Comment: Would i need to touch my application-context.xml for calling the Spring service from Wicket.

Comment: Yes, of course you would need to add your IContactService bean to the Spring application context. Someone has to create and provide the IContact service implementation to Wicket

Comment: To clarify a bit. Using @SpringBean without annotation params auto-wires by type, so a long as there's a bean implementing IContact in the application context config, it will be injected. It is also possible to specify bean names on the annotation if there are multiple alternatives.

Comment: The code for setting up annotation support is at https://cwiki.apache.org/WICKET/spring.html under section "Annotation-based Approach".